# Cannot expand and concatenate GCC macros into one

Tags: c, gcc

I have a set of #defines like that:

```
#define PORTA port_a
#define PORTB port_b
#define PORTC port_c
```

And some re-definitions of these into:

```
#define MY_PORT1 PORTA
#define MY_PORT2 PORTB
#define MY_PORT3 PORTC
```

And also a series of `xxx_set(param1, param2)` functions where `xxx` belongs to each PORTx, so:

```
PORTA_set(param1, param2)
PORTB_set(param1, param2)
PORTC_set(param1, param2)
```

I need to call these functions but using a single one, with my "custom port name" as the first parameter, so example:

`set(MY_PORT1, param1, param2)` must expand to `PORTA_set(param1, param2)`, and so on.

I tried after reading [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28740611/c-preprocessor-concatenation-of-another-define) [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17699443/generating-function-names-with-strings-using-macros-in-c) questions, related to expansion of macros into concatenations:

```
#define CAT_I( x, y ) x ## y
#define CAT( x, y ) CAT_I( x, y )
#define set( port, param1, param2 ) CAT( port, _set )(param1, param2)
```

But this throws me error

```
expected ';' before '_set'
pasting ")" and "_set" does not give a valid preprocessing token
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `pasting ")" and "_set"`  what does `port_a` expand to? Is there no "in expansion of.. in expansion of..." messages? Are there no "file:line:column" in error messages? Please post the full error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have:

```
#define port_a (something something)
```

which then does not work, because preprocessor can't concatenate `)` with `_set`. No, you can't "halfway" expand a macro.

But why write all these `PORT` all the time. Just write the letters.

```
#define PORTA port_a
#define PORTB port_b
#define PORTC port_c

#define MY_PORT1   A
#define MY_PORT2   B
#define MY_PORT3   C

#define _set_in(x) PORT##x##_set
#define set(port, param1, param2)  _set_in(port)(param1, param2)
```

Comment: This is the most acceptable for my situation. And yes, "port_a" was a way to simplify my code, but in reality it is a variable wrapped into "( )". Now it is clear and I've followed your suggestion regarding the single letters.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've just got too many macros. Not sure why the token pasting examples all use macros called `CAT`. I don't think it helps, and it seems to be adding excessive complexity.

`#define setport( port, param1, param2 ) port##_set(param1, param2)` ought to work.

Note that it's a bad idea to use `set` as the name of a macro and part of the definition. That's why this macro is called `setport`

Answer (score 0):

> I need to call these functions but using a single one, with my "custom port name" as the first parameter

If that is the purpose, you might want to consider a different approach, which uses C11 generic selection:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Define some helper types or tags.
typedef struct PORTA PORTA;
typedef struct PORTB PORTB;
typedef struct PORTC PORTC;

typedef PORTA port_a;
typedef PORTB port_b;
typedef PORTC port_c;

typedef PORTA MY_PORT1;
typedef PORTB MY_PORT2;
typedef PORTC MY_PORT3;

// The actual functions to be called:
void PORTA_set(int a, int b) {
    printf("PORT A   args: %d %d\n", a, b);
}

void PORTB_set(int a, int b) {
    printf("PORT B   args: %d %d\n", a, b);
}

void PORTC_set(int a, int b) {
    printf("PORT C   args: %d %d\n", a, b);
}

// Macroes that perform the selection:
#define set_impl(X, a, b) _Generic( X, \
                                    PORTA*: PORTA_set, \
                                    PORTB*: PORTB_set, \
                                    PORTC*: PORTC_set \
)(a, b)

#define set_(type, a, b) set_impl((type *)NULL, (a), (b))

int main(void)
{
    // Calls with the wanted interface.
    set_(port_a, 0, 1);
    set_(MY_PORT2, 42, 17);
    set_(PORTC, 8, 99);

    // Direct call example.
    PORTC_set(-3, 0);
}
```

Testable [here](https://godbolt.org/z/sxonhz9f9).